# PhotoView. При Zoom'e проседает FPS

Tags: java, android, imageview

[PhotoView](https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView) используется для "зумирования" PNG изображений. При "зумировании" проседает FPS даже на моем galaxy s6 edge. вот код активити:

`public class PortfolioFullScreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
ImageView fullScreenImage;
PhotoViewAttacher photoViewAttacher;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.portfolio_page_activity);

    fullScreenImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_full_screen);

    Intent intent = getIntent();

    int position = intent.getIntExtra("position", 100);

    switch (position){
        case 0:
            fullScreenImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.social_trading);
            break;
        case 1:
            fullScreenImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.social_trading);
            break;
        case 2:
            fullScreenImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.social_trading);
            break;
        case 3:
            fullScreenImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.social_trading);
            break;
        case 4:
            fullScreenImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.social_trading);
            break;
        case 5:
            fullScreenImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.social_trading);
            break;
        default:
            Toast.makeText(PortfolioFullScreenActivity.this, "Что-то пошло не так", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    photoViewAttacher = new PhotoViewAttacher(fullScreenImage,true);
}
```

}`
А layout файл:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Activities.PortfolioFullScreenActivity">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/image_full_screen"/>
</RelativeLayout>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Слушай. Я знаю что тебе нужно!!! Рекомендую скелить отображаемое изображение (На пикассо) Как я понимаю, ты пытаешь отобразить изображение очень высокого разрешения. Ну а на самом деле, если ты отскелишь изображение на разрешение FullHD (1080x1080) методом centerInstance то никаких визульных изменений ты не заметишь. Но работать будет в разы быстрее)))

```
Picasso.with(context)
            .load(new File(picPath))
            .resize(MAX_WIDTH, MAX_HEIGHT)
            .centerInside()
            .into(imageView, new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {
                    Bitmap bmp = ((BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
                    progressBar.setVisibility(visible);
                }

                @Override
                public void onError() {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(visible);
                }
            });
```

Comment: Да, ты прав, большое спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Как оптимизацию могу предложить использовать такую конструкцию:

```
imageView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
```

А далее - отображаем зафиксированный bitmap вместо оригинального изображения, увеличенного инструментом.

Если вновь происходит событие зума - снова берём результат - фиксируем его в битмэп и отображаем.

Правда тогда возникнут проблемы - когда убирать из вида контейнер отображения `PhotoView` и когда его возвращать и в каком состоянии.

Но решение тоже вроде бы очевидно: раз у `PhotoView` всё хорошо с событиями - просто запоминаем последние параметры масштабирования и сохраняем их в буферную переменную. Когда возникает событие изменения масштаба - восстанавливаем PhotoView с параметром масштабирования и позиции рамки, убираем Bitmap-"снимок" и ждём, когда можно вновь взять новый снимок для отображения.

Просадки в FPS будут только в моменты изменения масштаба изображения.

Comment: UPD: ещё торможение FPS может быть сдледствием того, что фрагменты сцены "вылезают" за границы экрана (может картинка масштабируемая "расползается") - но это больше относится к игрострою , и вряд ли применимо в данном вопросе.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, но думаю просто использовать картинки меньшего разрешения(2000х2300 - сейчас).

Answer (score 1):

Я тоже использовал данную библиотеку. Она очень плохо работает когда дело доходит до подгрузки файлов из вне и использования внутри ViewPager. Возможно не по теме (Я тебе не смогу подсказать почему у тебя тормозит FPS) но я могу прорекомендовать кое что другое. А именно вот это View

[TouchImageView.java](https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView/blob/master/src/com/ortiz/touch/TouchImageView.java)

```
vh.photoView = (TouchImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.photo);
vh.photoView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

Никакого просидания fps не наблюдаю в Sony Xperia Z1

**Обновление**

Рекомендую склеить отображаемое изображение (например, на пикассо). Как я понимаю, вы пытаетесь отобразить изображение очень высокого разрешения. Ну а на самом деле, если ты отсекаешь изображение на разрешение FullHD (1080x1080) методом `centerInstance`, то никаких визуальных изменений вы не заметите. Но работать будет в разы быстрее.

Comment: Попробовал, к сожалению эффект тот же, что очень даже странно.