# Как загрузить в ScrollView картинку размером 3000х5000 px с возможностью увеличения изображения

Tags: android, изображения, picasso, android-scrollview

Имеется большое изображение. Хотелось бы что это изображение было читабельным. Т.е. необходима возможность увеличивать его. Использовал Picaso. но что-то не так
вот код активити.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
    android:scaleType="matrix"
    android:id="@+id/eur__e__s10__all_001"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

      <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="@string/s10100BA270"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

     <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="@string/s10100BA260"
         android:layout_below="@+id/eur__e__s10__all_001"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Вот код java:

```
public class Eur_S10_ALL_E_001 extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_eur__s10__all__e_001);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.eur__e__s10__all_001);
    Picasso.with(this)
            .load(R.drawable.s10_001_01)
            .resize(500,300)
            .into(imageView);





    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте PhotoView из поста http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/525795/photoview-%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8-zoome-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-fps/525801#525801

Comment: "Что-то не так" - это вы имеете в виду, что слишком хорошее качество и его надо уменьшить?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Ну в идеале, нужно чтобы можно было увеличить изображение без потери его качества.

Comment: @Nexx, вы слишком расплывчато сформулировали вопрос. Кроме первого коммента ничего сказать ибо непонятно что именно из означенных задач ваш код не сделал. "Что-то не так" - ничего не объясняет.

Answer (score 1):

Я подключил вот эту [библиотеку](https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView) и меня это устраивает. Cпасибо @DimXenon